# In Google Cloud Endpoints how return dynamic Json

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I want return a dynamic JSON object from my endpoint, to add properties on the fly without changing any method signature.

Comment: Could you provide some code or more detail that describes the current design of your endpoint?

Comment: @JamieNiemasik, I solved by returning a list of custom wrapping  value for each property. And I will leave the question open in case someone have a more low level solution. Thanks you very much for your activity these days in this site.

Answer (score 1):

It feels rather contrary to the design of endpoints, but I found it very useful to have endpoints that could accept or return arbitrary JSON objects.  So I use a class like this in my endpoint method:

```
public class DataParcel {
  public Integer obj_type = -1;
  public List<String> json_objects = null;  // new ArrayList<String>();
```

The only complication is which JSON library to use - the JSON encoding/decoding is no longer done for you automatically.